# Should I use FOR UPDATE in SELECT subquery here DELETE FROM table WHERE id = any(array(SELECT id FROM table WHERE ... LIMIT 100))

Tags: postgresql

I know if I use ctid I should use FOR UPDATE in sub-query because row can be updated by another transaction while my transaction tries to delete it. As result this row will not be deleted. The right way:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ctid = any(array(
    SELECT ctid
    FROM table
    WHERE ...
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE));
```

If I use primary key same way should I need to use FOR UPDATE in SELECT sub-query? If not, why not?

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = any(array(
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE ...
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same could happen with the primary key, although I'd expect it to happen less often (primary keys should not change).

But you need that `FOR UPDATE` not only because the row could be modified: without it, the subquery would also see rows that are being deleted by a concurrent statement, and which will prove non-existent when you try to delete them.

Finally, it would be a good thing to have an `ORDER BY` in the subquery that can use an index. Then all such queries will try to lock rows in the same order, which reduces the likelihood of deadlocks.